# Print individual entity types from MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql

I don't understand much of PHP or MySQL, but I have this bit of code that prints the overall number of `qa_userfavorites` from the Database, for the current logged in user.

And what I'm trying to do now is print each and individual entityType with their correspondent count number, but can't figure how.
I've tried a bunch of different things but at this point I'm just making stuff up.

### Print example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

> Q - 1
> T - 2
> U - 2

### Code:

```
$userid = qa_get_logged_in_userid(); // id of currently logged in user 
$getFCount = qa_db_read_all_assoc(qa_db_query_sub('
    SELECT userid FROM qa_userfavorites
    WHERE userid = '. $userid .'
'));

$getFCount = count($getFCount); //count item in array
echo $getFCount;
```

### MySQL `qa_userfavorites` table screenshot:

[image]

Comment: `SELECT entitytype, COUNT(entitytype) FROM qa_userfavourites GROUP BY entitytype`

Comment: Oh sorry @ADyson I may have not expressed myself that well. Currently with the code you provided is only printing the number 3, which I figure is the number of rows of type/entitytypes. And I wanted to print how many instances are for each letter.  
For example `Q` has only one and `T` and `U` have 2 instances each. So I wanted to print 1/2/2 . Maybe now it's more clarified? :S

Comment: I think I got it to work!!
`SELECT userid FROM qa_userfavorites WHERE entitytype = "Q"`
Still will have to check if's working for other users without the `userid` part. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Update including userid  
`SELECT userid FROM qa_userfavorites WHERE entitytype = "Q" AND userid = '. $userid .'`